# What could be the reason for not displaying a line graph on the panel rangeslider_visible Plotly?

Tags: python, plotly

I display different graphs, use different parameters for them. Faced with the fact that sometimes the lower panel `rangeslider_visible` under the main chart does not display charts.

Some code:

```
if select_style == 'Line graph':
   fig4 = px.line(df_region_now, x='Date', y=select_metrics,
                  color_discrete_sequence=palette_plot,
                  markers=marker_setup)
   fig4.update_xaxes(rangeslider_visible=True)
   fig4.update_layout(xaxis_title='Date',
                      yaxis_title='Number',
                      width=250, height=700,
                      hovermode='x unified')
   st.plotly_chart(fig4, use_container_width=True)
```

These are the results I get within a single graph, that is, sometimes everything works as it should, and sometimes the graphs disappear:

[image]

[image]

[image]

It has been clearly seen that this depends on if there is more than one metric in the full chart visualization. Although I don’t see this in other charts, the same `px.bar` works fine. Plotly version 5.6.0

Answer (score 1):

Can you please provide your input data? Also a subselection as an example input is okay.

My guess is that your column `df_region_now['Date']`

```
type(df_region_now['Date'])
>>> object
```

is of type object and not timestamp. To ensure multiple lines within `rangeslider` the date column must be of type `timestamp`.

Hope this solves your issue.

Comment: hello, its ```Date datetime64[ns]```. Here is an example of writing a value: ```2020-03-27T00:00:00```

Comment: I tried converting everything to a timestamp, but there was no difference. Everything is exactly the same